# Document height taller because of position relative

Tags: html, css

I am working with 2 divs positioned relative and overlapping each other with a position of top:-400px.

All the content below it has a top of -800px so that the content pushes up. Everything displays fine how ever there is 800px of space at the bottom of the page because the browser still thinks that the content is that far down when it is actually -400px up.

Help?

Here is my code for you to view : http://theproagency.com/WeddingHub

I am looking for a CSS fix - I can already fix this with JS with 
document.height = document.height - 800px or w.e

All help appreciated.

Thanks

p.s. I also would like to know how to fix this in all situations. What if this happens in future situations when I am building websites? I thought I was experienced at building websites but this one has caught me in a pickle

Comment: Why are they positioned like that? Just have them positioned naturally, instead of moving the bottom one on top of the top one.

Comment: Are you positioning everything like this with negative top positions so that you could put the slider over `.flowerBG`?

Comment: +michael coker - Yes that is correct. I also have a opaque black BG over the flowers to change their brightness as more areas of my photoshop design reuse the same flowers at different opaque values both brighter and darker.

Comment: +tricksfortheweb - you are right - I tried that but I could not get my slider to go over it without position:relative and top:-400px.

Comment: Hi, I was just tinkering with the values of your CSS, will this help in anyway? .mainContent {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 26%;
}

Comment: http://theproagency.com/weddinghub2/ fixed it - absolute positioning on the inner elements was key with the parent elements set to relative! Thank you guys.

Comment: Hey + utkarsh bais, I did not get to look at your solution. Thank you so much for replying. Actually it does not work but it is close - too much margin on the left side. Good info though. I believe position absolute is enough, if I made a container. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I made some changes. Please copy just this body to your code. you should have a backup.

```
<body>
<header class="topBar">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="socialMedia"><a href="#"><img src="images/fbico.jpg" width="29" height="30" alt=""></a><a href="#"><img src="images/linkedinico.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt=""></a><a href="#"><img src="images/twitterico.jpg" width="30" height="30" alt=""></a></div>
    <nav class="secondaryNav">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="mailto:support@weddinghubs.com">support@weddinghubs.com</a></li>
            <li class="phoneNumberBTN teal"><a href="tel:1-360-870-1081" class="telLarge">1 (360) 870-1081</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div class="clearfloat"></div>
</div>
</header>
<div class="aboveSlider">
<div class="wrapper">
    <nav class="topNav">
        <ul>
            <li class="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" width="148" height="60" alt=""></a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Packages</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Designs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">We Can Help</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
</div>
<!--I removed your class="opaqueOverlay". And also I included wrapper class to flowerBG class. -->
<div class="flowerBG">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="slider">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Wedding websites &amp; invitations</h1>
            <h5>We specialize in websites &amp; invitations for the special day.</h5>
        </hgroup>
        <a href="#">
            <div class="getStartedBTN">Get Started</div>
        </a> </div>
</div>
</div>

<!--end wrapper and slider -->
<!--begin mainContent .wrapper -->
<main role="main" class="mainContent wrapper">
<article>
    <header>
        <hgroup class="us">
            <h1 class="weare">The Wedding Specialists</h1>
            <h2 class="wedo">Invites, designs &amp; more.</h2>
        </hgroup>
    </header>
    <p class="contentLeft"> Hello,<br>
        <br>
        We are weddinghubs.com and we specialize in websites &amp; invitations for fiances
        and newly weds. Our service is invaluable for any new couple who is planning on
        marriage. We handle everything from domain registration, page creation and even let you choose when you want the website and service to go live. We also have password protection services and auto account creation for digital invitee’s so only select guests will be able to see your beautiful website. Away from the eyes of the public. Though if you would like a public website - we will do and handle that too. As we understand weddings are amazing milestones. The start to the next chapter of your life and people around you.<br>
        <br>
        <strong>Regards,</strong><br>
        <span class="signature">Kyle L.Scott</span><br>
        WeddingHubs.com Owner </p>
    <aside class="information">
        <h1>Website Features</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>RSVP Tracker</li>
            <li>Photosharing</li>
            <li>Wedding Countdown</li>
            <li>Unique Designs</li>
            <li>Driving Directions</li>
            <li>and so much more.</li>
        </ul>
    </aside>
</article>
</main>
</body>
```

And also I made some changes of class="flowerBG" in css. I removed top spaces.  I used CSS3 Gradients.

```
.flowerBG {
height: 400px;
position: relative;
background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0 ,0 , .55), rgba(0, 0 ,0 , .55)), url(../images/banner.jpg);}
```

changes of class="slider" in css. I removed top spaces.

```
.slider {
height: 400px;
position: relative;
```

}

Changes of mainContent class in css. I removed top spaces.

```
.mainContent {
position: relative;
}
```

I hope you got a solution now.
Thank you!